# Struts2-File Upload Interceptor: after uploading file name is not appearing

Tags: struts2

In my struts2 application I am using “File Upload Interceptor”. Its running well but after uploading when same jsp page appears it does not show browsed file name in the textbox of `<s:file>` tag i.e textbox comes empty after successful uploading.
Here is my code snippet-

**main.jsp**

```
<s:form action="smAction" enctype="multipart/form-data" theme="simple">
<s:file name="sample"/>
<s:submit action="uploadSample" value="All upload" />
</s:form>
```

**struts.xml**

```
<action name=" uploadSample " class=" UploadMySample">
<interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
<result name="input"> /login.jsp</result>
<result name="success">/main.jsp</result>
</action>
```

**UploadMySample.java**

```
public class UploadMySample extends ActionSupport {            
  private File sample;
  private String sampleContentType;
  private String sampleFileName;

  public File getSample () {
      return sample; 
  }
  public void setSample (File sample) {
      this. sample = sample;
  }
  //Here is the file uploading code
  return SUCCESS; 

}
```

**Please suggest.**

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem of Struts. For security reasons modern browser don't allow to set a value for file upload fields. If you want to display the file name after the upload you'll have to use simple text.